# How to get NSDictionary JSON data in another class in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am new to iPhone programming.I have create one method call normallogin in ClassA .But iam call this method in ClassB if call this method,it will connect with server and get JSON data from server in `didFinishLoading` method in classA and i have stored in new JSON object.Now i want to get new JSON object in classB new `NSDictionary` object.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
 NSString * returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@returnStringreturnString", returnString);

  NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                            options:0
                                                              error:nil];
  NSLog(@"%@newJSON:---", newJSON);
}
```

How to get new JSON object data in classB.for that i am using below code for
I am calling normallogin method in classB using below code.Every thing is working fine.But i want to get new JSON data in ClassB. Please tell me how to do get data.

```
loginconnectiomm *lconnection =[[loginconnectiomm alloc]init];
 [lconnection normallogin];
```

Comment: use NSUserDefault for add and remove

Comment: Try to learn about delegation. It's common design pattern in iOS. Instead of making any tweak just give 1-2 hours in learning it and apply it to your problem. [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm) and [here](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002) are the tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to achieve what you are asking for, but there a probably more.

**1) Using a delegate**

Set ObjectB as Delegate of ObjectA. Basically it's a weak instance variable of A and it conforms to a protocol. Therefore in your ClassA.h file define (before the interface-block of ClassA):

```
@class ClassA;    // The interface of ClassA is defined later, so we need to assure that ClassA exists ("forward declaration").
@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject>
-(void)objectA:(ClassA*)objectA didFinishLoading:(NSDictionary*)dict;
@end
```

Then you could modify your code as follows (I left out the logs):

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString * returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:nil];
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(objectA:didFinishLoading:)])
    {
        [self.delegate objectA:self didFinishLoading:newJSON];
    }
}
```

**2) Using a block**

You could pass in a block of code that gets executed in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. Therefore define a property in ClassA for the block:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^didFinishLoadingHandler)(NSDictionary*);
```

Add

```
self.didFinishLoadingHandler(newJSON);
self.didFinishLoadingHandler = nil;
```

to the bottom of `didFinishLoading`. This executes the the block and resets the property.

In `normallogin` store the passed in block in the property. In ObjectB do something like:

```
__block NSDictionary* jsonDict = nil;
loginconnectiomm *lconnection =[[loginconnectiomm alloc]init];
[lconnection normallogin:^(NSDictionary* json){
    jsonDict = json;
}];
```

**UPDATE**

Change declaration of `-(void)normallogin;` to `-(void)normallogin:(void(^)(NSDictionary*))didFinishLoadingHandler;`. Then in implementation do something like

```
-(void)normallogin:(void(^)(NSDictionary*))didFinishLoadingHandler
{
    self.didFinishLoadingHandler = didFinishLoadingHandler;
    // Rest of the stuff from your normallogin
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank u for giving replay..Ya using blocks i tried but it showing error in this line [lconnection normallogin:^(NSDictionary* jsson)..Error is like this no visible @interface for declares the selector 'normallogin'

Comment: Updated my answer to include that part ;)

Comment: One side-note: Since you're new to iPhone development (and probably Objective-C) you should take your time to look at a coding style guide (e.g. this one: [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) or this one: [Ray Wenderlich Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/raywenderlich/objective-c-style-guide)). There are arguable points in each and every one of them, but most of the stuff written really helps to obtain readability when asking for help in general or on sites like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class representing data you get after parsing `JSON` responce.
Add one `singleton class` which will give access to objects of this class from any view controller you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a return type function that can provide you return. like this

```
-(NSDictionary *) normallogin{

NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0   error:nil];
 //Note : Here I write down this dictionary only for example .. Please implement your code here and that dictionary you are getting return this . 
return newJSON;

}
```

And call this function and get in return dictionary like this

```
loginconnectiomm *lconnection =[[loginconnectiomm alloc]init];
 NSDictionary *returnDic = [lconnection normallogin];
```

now you can use returnDic for data

Comment: Thanks for giving replay..Here where can i call -(NSDictionary *)normallogin

Comment: In which call you are getting data in server.. and one more thing, you need to declare this function in .m class

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using delegate. Your Class B must confirm to a protocol say RespondeDelegate.

```
@Protocol ResponseDelegate<NSObject> 
-(Void)workWithJsonResponse:(NSDictionary *)response;
@end
```

In ClassA.h create a property as below

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) id<ResponseDelegate> delegate;
```

In class A.m file synthesize the delegate property

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{NSString * returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:nil];
ClassB *obj = [[ClassB alloc] init]; // initialize your obj as per your convenience
obj.delegate = self;
[obj.delegate workWithJsonResponse:newJSON];
```

Do this in ClassB.h file

```
@Interface ClassB:UIViewController<ResponseDelegate>
```

In ClassB.m file handle/implemnt the delegate method

```
-(Void)workWithJsonResponse:(NSDictionary *)response {
//DO the stuff here
}
```

Hope this will work for you.If any issue let me know.